# which class should I use to collect and store different data types?

Tags: java, android

My `Sqlite` Database has several columns with different data types. Now, I want to retrieve a row which has different data types and store it in one object.

Which data type or class should I use?

Comment: Make a class that holds some variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make a list of objects:

```
int numberOfObjects = 10;
ArrayList<Obj> lst = new ArrayList<Obj>(numberOfObjects);
```

Answer (score 0):

That depends on how you are going to use it later.. The

> resultset

can hold all the datatypes.Later you can retreive every coloumn value from it as a string.

Comment: Consider changing this post to a comment.

Comment: May be i would. If you can give me a valid reason

Comment: @Jain I am retrieving rows from the database to create a report. so each row should formulate a report. i hope it is clear now

Comment: Got it, just get the data as string from the Resultset object and firmulate the report in java code.

Comment: @Jain because it's not a real answer. It only throws in a `hint` and doesn't explain much or show some example.

Comment: @DerGolem next time I would. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Cursor and a Custom Object is just fine.

```
class YourDataClass {
  int id;
  String data;
  byte[] rawdata;
  public String getData() { return data; }
  public String setData(String data) { this.data = data; }
  // .... other getters and setters
}


Cursor yourCursor = database.rawQuery("select * from blub");
if (yourCursor != null & yourCursor.size() > 0 && yourCursor.moveToFirst) {
    YourDataClass yourObject = new YourObject;
    yourObject.setId(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("id"));
    yourObject.setData(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("data"));
... whatever.

}
```